# Show progress of very long postgres procedure (transmit data out of transaction before it ends up)

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I tried to create tables, but it was useless because each begin-end block wrapped in transaction in postgres, so I can't see any changes before the end of transaction.
The only solution is rising INFO, I use it to show current step of procedure, but its not exactly what I am looking for. I need to know detailed data of current calculations, because every step can take a few hours. 
Please suggest me the way to transmit data out of transaction before it ends up.

UPD: I've found the way to transmit progress: I can increase sequences from within my procedure, and  read them from other connection. http://blog.endpoint.com/2010/04/viewing-postgres-function-progress-from.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dblink extension to connect back to the database and execute statements on a different connection. This is also commonly used for logging errors before a transaction rolls back, for example.

Quick demonstration:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink; -- or run the script from contrib before version 9.1

select * from dblink('dbname=steve', $$
       select datname, procpid, current_query from pg_stat_activity
      $$) r(datname name, pid int, current_query text);
```

produces:

```
 datname | pid  |                            current_query                            
---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 steve   | 8535 | select * from dblink('dbname=steve', $$                            +
         |      |        select datname, procpid, current_query from pg_stat_activity+
         |      |       $$) r(datname name,                                          +
         |      |           pid int, current_query text);
 steve   | 9235 |                                                                    +
         |      |        select datname, procpid, current_query from pg_stat_activity+
         |      |
```

so you can see that these are two separate sessions. dblink provides functionality to open a persistent connection etc. that this simple usage skips over. Provided that you already have a schema to put the progress information into, then you can simply call dblink() to populate/update it via the second connection, while your first connection continues to execute its long transaction.

Comment: I've read the manual, but can't figure out how to use dblink in my issue. Couldn't you explain how to use it more detailed?

Comment: I've added a quite demo of how to use dblink to the answer.